# Use of plurals when talking about a boxes owner?

Tags: grammatical-number

I have the following technical detail to log in work:

> There is no communication between each
>   of the ComboBoxes containers

The component is called a ComboBox in singular. Is this correct, or do 
I need to add an apostrophe to ComboBoxes?

Comment: Brian, it's often better to **be long-winded**.  Really spell it out - at length. And repeat yourself redundantly. *There is no communication between any ComboBox container, and, any other ComboBox container.  It's impossible for any ComboBox container, to communicate with any other ComboBox container. This applies to every ComboBox container.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If each container contains one or several ComboBoxes, it might be better to use *ComboBox containers* instead, in the same way we use *apple containers* or *orange containers* to describe containers containing apples or oranges.

Grammatically, *ComboBox containers* is a compound noun with *containers* modified by *ComboBox*.

Comment: +1 That's what I thought too. On the other hand, if they are containers within the ComboBoxes, or part of the ComboBoxes (my knowledge of UI design is admittedly minuscule), then he may have to say _ComboBoxes' containers_.

Comment: Lovely stuff, both answers appreciated. Now I know where the apostrophe would go, and also ComboBox containers sounds better than what I had

Answer (score 0):

> There is no communication between each of the ComboBoxes containers.

A noun that is used as modifier is used in its singular form, in English; see for example *32-bit architecture*.

Instead of using *each of*, which is better used in sentences like *Doug had money from each of his five uncles*, I would use *each*; the sentence would become

> There is no communication between each ComboBox container.

Alternatively, it can be changed to

> There is no communication between the ComboBox containers.

Comment: "between each *singular-noun*" is somewhat problematic.  I like your last version best.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard a rule that inanimate objects should not take a possessive. Here is a way to both obey the rule and avoid the apostrophe:

> There is no communication among the containers of ComboBoxes.

Comment: That's weird. The airplane's wings. The jacket's sleeves. The Earth's atmosphere. The flower's smell. The dessert's flavor. The car's engine. The chair's legs. The bed's softness. What's wrong with these? I also find your suggested phrasing awkward.

Comment: @ErikE, see this Chicago Manual of Style entry for "Possessives and attributes" at http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/CMS_FAQ/PossessivesandAttributives/PossessivesandAttributives22.html. The OP question falls under the category of "When a possessive gets ugly, give it up." Here are some others that I consider ugly and harsh on the ear: "The lens's aperture," "The Lentz's ship," "Robert Reich's exchange," and "The ComboBoxes's communication." Whether inanimate objects take a possessive for attributes is in a state of flux. Strunk & White say "Never," CMOS says "Sometimes."

Comment: Style manuals flux away. I'll stop saying "the airplane's wings" when we all have pocket teleportation devices. :)